# Insert a list of objects using MyBatis 3

Tags: java, list, syntax, insert, mybatis

I've tried to insert a list in a database but I've got some the error: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: SqlSession operation; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00913: too many values (...).

The code that I've used:

```
<insert id="insertListMyObject" parameterType="java.util.List" >
INSERT INTO my_table
   (ID_ITEM,
    ATT1,
    ATT2)
    VALUES
   <foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index" open="(" close=")" separator=",">
    #{item.idItem, jdbcType=BIGINT},
    #{item.att1, jdbcType=INTEGER},
    #{item.att2, jdbcType=STRING}
       </foreach>   
</insert>
```

My dao cals the method:

```
SqlSessionTemplate().insert(MAPPER+".insertListMyObject", parameterList);
```

Where the parameterList is:

```
List<MyObjects>.
```

Does someone have a clue about what's this error? Or if does exists a better way to do multiples inserts operation.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Set the separator as given below

```
separator="),("
```

Answer (score 6):

by using following query you may insert multiple records at a time using Mybatis and Oracle.

```
<insert id="insertListMyObject" parameterType="map" >
BEGIN
                            insert into table_name values (11,11);
                            insert into table_name2 values (11,112);
            END;
</insert>
```

this is how i did for oracle and it works. Note that `parameterType=map` is not necessary a map it can be anything according to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

config log4j to mybatis ,you can find the bugs.

trying

```
<insert id="insertListMyObject" parameterType="java.util.List" >
INSERT INTO my_table
   (ID_ITEM,
    ATT1,
    ATT2)
    VALUES
   <foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index"  separator=",">
    (#{item.idItem, jdbcType=BIGINT},
    #{item.att1, jdbcType=INTEGER},
    #{item.att2, jdbcType=STRING})
       </foreach>   
</insert>
```

Comment: In my case, I trust in useGeneratedKeys="true" to create automatic IDs for the items in the foreach. Is it possible to retrieve these new IDs?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you can do this with an [oracle INSERT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems025.htm) statement. The INSERT with VALUES (other than the one with the subquery) does allow values for one row only!

To do so, try a batch insert. An MyBatis example can be found [here](http://amitsavm.blogspot.com/2011/11/mybatis-batch-insert.html).

Answer (score 0):

something like this in your DAO layer might help

```
public class MyBatisDao
{

    private SqlSessionFactory mSqlSessionFactory;
    public void insertUsers(List<User> users) {
    SqlSession session = mSqlSessionFactory.openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH);
    try {
        for(User user:users)
        {
          session.insert("com.you.insertUsers",user);
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }   
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use batch, it is much better, and it is standard. This query will not work on some databases (Oracle for example).